# How long will the strike last?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-replacements

In [*The Replacements* (2000)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0191397/), is there ever a date mentioned for a possible end to the Pros' strike? If not, how does the replacement team know when it's their last game?

I don't recall hearing an expected end date, just that they want more money and that the strike will continue until they get it.

It just seems as though, once the original QB crosses the picket line, the replacement team all knows it's going to be their last game. But the rest of the original team has not crossed the picket line yet.

Answer (score 2):

No concrete date was ever given, because no one knew when the players demands would be met.

By the way, there's a little bit of precedent here.  On several occasions a strike actually happened, and in 1987 the NFL [played 3 weeks with replacement players](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1987_NFL_season).

> The NFLPA went on strike for a month in 1987 upon the expiration of
>   the 1982 CBA; the league's free-agent policy was the major matter in
>   dispute. This time, however, the strike only canceled one week of the
>   season. For three weeks, the NFL staged games with hastily assembled
>   replacement teams, made up principally of players cut during training
>   camp and players left out of work from the closure of the United
>   States Football League two years prior (along with, to a lesser
>   extent, the Montreal Alouettes of the CFL, who had folded just three
>   months prior to the strike). They were joined by a few veterans who
>   crossed the picket lines, including New York Jets defensive end Mark
>   Gastineau, Dallas Cowboys defensive tackle Randy White, San Francisco
>   49ers quarterback Joe Montana, New England Patriots quarterback Doug
>   Flutie, and Seattle Seahawks wide receiver Steve Largent.

Some of the replacement players from that season were (no BS) [Death Row Records mogul Suge Knight](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suge_Knight#Early_life) and [Saints coach Sean Payton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sean_Payton#Playing_career).  Oilers replacement linebacker Eugene Seale stuck around long enough to be selected All-Pro on Special Teams the following year, and Saints replacement QB John Fourcade managed to keep himself in the league for 3 years following the strike.

BTW, regarding the movie The Replacements...

> The final replacement game was a Monday Night Football matchup on
>   October 19, 1987 between the Washington Redskins at the Dallas
>   Cowboys. The Redskins were the lone NFL team not to have any players
>   cross the picket line and were surprising 13-7 victors over the
>   Cowboys who had plenty of big name players cross the picket line. This
>   game was the inspiration behind the Gene Hackman and Keanu Reeves 2000
>   movie The Replacements.

Answer (score 1):

There wasn't a date mentioned, but the coach does say that the strike will end the next day. I didn't find a youtube link to it, so this will have to do. [From here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Replacements_(film)):

> McGinty tells the replacements that **the strike will officially end the next day**, giving the players incentive to give everything they have left.